# Check if a value is null before casting and assigning

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'm using c# .net 2.0 and need to check if the value returned from my method that I am assigning my object to is null.

My code is

```
MyObjectValue myObjectValue= (MyObjectValue) myObjectField.GetFieldValue();
```

In this instance the value returned by myObjectField.GetFieldValue() could be null and I want to check this before assigning to myObjectValue. At the moment it throws an exception object reference not set to a value of an object.

The actual line of code is using the SharePoint API

```
SPFieldUserValue lawyerResponsibleFieldValue = 
    (SPFieldUserValue)lawyerResponsibleUserField.GetFieldValue(
              workflowProperties.Item[lawyerResponsibleUserField.Id].ToString());
```

Comment: Obivously an assignment can't throw, so your problem is that `myObjectField` is null, not the return value or something within the `GetFieldValue` method.

Comment: @John: Or the cast fails, which it would if `MyObjectValue` is a value type.

Comment: That actual line of code is almost *nothing* like the original. You've introduced many, many potential causes of a NullReferenceException. See my edit.

Comment: Good grief, that's a heck of a line of code. You need to decompose it; test each value for null, to see where the problem is.

Comment: List of possible causes of NullReferenceExceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net/4660186#4660186

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above code won't throw a `NullReferenceException` if `myObjectField` itself is non-null, unless `MyObjectValue` is a value type. Are you sure the problem isn't that you're then *using* `myObjectValue` without checking whether or not it's null?

However, assuming `GetFieldValue` returns `object`, the simplest approach is simply to use a temporary variable:

```
object tmp = myObjectField.GetFieldValue();
if (tmp != null)
{
    MyObjectValue myObjectValue = (MyObjectValue) tmp;
    // Use myObjectValue here
}
```

Obviously this will work whether `MyObjectValue` is a reference type or a value type.

EDIT: Now that you've posted the full line of code, there are *loads* of places where it could be throwing a NullReferenceException. I strongly suggest that you break up that one line into *several* lines to find out what's going on.

Comment: @nav: Is "MyObjectValue" a value type or a reference type?

Comment: from his edit, `MyObjectValue` is actually `SPFieldUserValue`, a reference type.

Comment: @Justin: Yup, and the edit completely changes the question :)

Answer (score 5):

C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015) introduced [Null-Conditionals](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators) (aka Elvis operator)...

instead of this...

```
myObjectValue = (myObjectValue == null) ? null : myObjectValue.child;
```

the following can be used...

```
myObjectValue = myObjectValue?.child;
```

Answer (score 4):

Anywhere you `.` something, it represents member access, if the left-hand side is a reference type (class) it could be null.

This snippet has several places where a null value might occur:

```
workflowProperties.Item[lawyerResponsibleUserField.Id].ToString()
                  ^                               ^   ^
```

I would first of all, break into a debugging session and check what values are present and read up on any documentation regarding the issue. Then I might reconsider writing the code like this.

```
if (lawyerResponsibleUserField != null
    && lawyerResponsibleUserField.Id != null)
{
    return Convert.ToString(workflowProperties != null 
            ? workflowProperties.Item[lawyerResponsibleUserField.Id] 
            : null
    )
}
```

*Assuming that these properties are reference types and could be null values.*

There are many ways to check for null and short circuit the evaluation. A good tip is to avoid using the `.ToString()` instance method and use the static method `Convert.ToString()` instead, it doesn't throw an exception if the passed value is null. The return value can still be null, but at least you don't have to worry about the supplied argument as much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really safe:

```
MyObjectValue myObjectValue = null;

if(myObjectField != null)
{
    object temp = myObjectField.GetFieldValue();
    if(temp != null)
    {
        myObjectValue = (MyObjectValue)temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(cast)null` is okay and results in `null` -- I "take advantage of" this a good bit. Sometimes it's for supplying type information to a method as well with type-inference, etc. Only the outside conditional is useful here. Example: `T Coerce<T>(object val, T defaultValue) { ... }; string s = Coerce(fuuba, (string)null);`

Comment: Previous comment doesn't address ValueTypes. Leaving for history, but "really safe" does apply without knowing type of MyObjectValue more.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that it's actually `myObjectField` that's null, not `myObjectField.GetFieldValue()`. If that's the case, then a simple check for null would work fine:

```
 MyObjectValue myObjectValue;
if  (myObjectField == null)
{
    // recover
}
else 
{
    myObjectValue = (MyObjectValue) myObjectField.GetFieldValue();
}
```

A few lines of debug code would verify that for you:

```
Console.WriteLine("myObjectField=" + myObjectField);
```

If you see `null` there, then it's `myObjectField` that's null.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an error elsewhere; if `MyObjectValue` is a reference type (a `class`, not a `struct`), then there should be no exception when casting `null` to your type. If `MyObjectValue` is a value type (a `struct`, not a `class`), then you cannot assign a null value to it.

You can use the coalescing operator to handle the case for nulls.

```
MyObjectValue value = (MyObjectValue)(field.GetFieldValue() ?? (object)someValidValue);
```

`someValidValue` represents what you'd like to use as the default value in the case that `GetFieldValue` returns `null`. This is slightly expensive, since casting `someValidValue` must be boxed to cast it to an object, but this should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Does no better. `(cast)null` is okay. Problem is `field` may be null. Unless I'm suffering from the question-edit bug. Might as well be `((MyObjectValue)field.GetFieldValue()) ?? someMyObjectValue` wrt. a NRE.

Comment: Oops on me. +1 because this does address when MyObjectValue is a ValueType. Other comment left for history.

Answer (score 1):

**Bellow suggestion is just a sample of null values**

if object is null then object.ToString() will raise error

in bellow codes i use *ComboBox* for samples.

so best way is check that

```
// 1)
if (cmb.SelectedValue == null)
{
   // do something
}
```

and if you want to use inline

```
// 2)
string strValue = (cmb.SelectedValue ?? "-1").ToString();
// or
string strValue = cmb.SelectedValue == null ? "-1" : cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

and last way is to handle error

```
// 3)
string strValue = "";
try
{
   strValue = cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
catch
{
  strValue = "-1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
if (myObjectField  != System.DBNull.Value))
{
    string variable = myObjectField.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public IQueryable GetOrderDetails()
    { 
        var _db = new ProductContext();
        IQueryable<OrderDetail> query = _db.OrderDetails;

        if (ddlOrder.SelectedValue != null && ddlOrder.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOrder.SelectedValue);

            query = query.Where(p => p.Username == User.Identity.Name && p.OrderId == id);
                }   
       else{ query = null; ddlOrder.Visible = false;btnSubmit.Visible = false; }
        return query;
           }
```

Comment: It would be helpful for @Van (and future users) to hear your explanation as to why this is the right answer.

Comment: If Drop down value is null or selected item is null or no data in dropdown list then we can use it.    if (ddlOrder.SelectedValue != null && ddlOrder.SelectedItem != null)